# Three.js texture does not load

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to make a model of planet Earth, but the texture doesn't load and I don't know why this happens, I tried to change the image format and also use it as an export link and it still doesn't work.

my code:

```js
import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.134.0'





const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(
);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);




renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight); 
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);




const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 50, 50), 
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('.img/global.jpeg')
        })
        
    
    );
    



scene.add(sphere);
camera.position.z = 15;


function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();
```

Comment: Please ensure with the browser dev tools whether the image is actually loaded or not. In many similar cases the path to the texture was wrong or the backend server did not properly serve an image.

Comment: thank you, i found out the error was the call
wrong = .img/global.jpeg
correct = img/global.jpeg

Answer (score 2):

My first suggestion is for you to split up your code into individual steps so you can pinpoint where the error is taking place. Additionally, `TextureLoader.load()` has [a few callback functions](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/TextureLoader) that you can help you determine if loading was successful or if it failed:

```js
const geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 50, 50);

const texLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const texture = texLoader.load(
    // Location
    '.img/global.jpeg', 

    // On success
    function(texture) {
        console.log("Success!");
        console.log(texture);
    },

    // Progress (ignored)
    undefined,

    // On error
    function(err) {
        console.log("Error");
        console.log(err);

    }
);

const mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture});
const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);
```

Then you can check your console to see what the logs are displaying.